# encoding multiple files in one variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am using multiple file upload option. After uploading it is showing 2 files uploaded but when i try to print encoded value in console it is only encoding and taking value of my last uploaded file. how do i encode multiple files at a time in a one variable.? Here is what i have tried.

```
    <html>
    <body>

<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();" multiple />
<div id="imgTest"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function encodeImageFileAsURL() {

    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

        var newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.src = srcData;

        document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
        //alert("Converted Base64 version is " + document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
    var reslut =    document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML; 
        console.log("Converted Base64 version is " +reslut);

      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use Array to store multiple values.

Comment: ` var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files; `return all files. You can loop on this.

Comment: I am not getting how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion to call `encodeImageFileAsURL` for each `.files`, substitute `.appendChild()` for `.innerHTML` if incremented variable is less than `filesSelected` `.length`; substitute `loadend` event for `load` event

```
  function encodeImageFileAsURL(index) {
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    index = index || 0;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0 && index < filesSelected.length) {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[index];

      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onloadend = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

        var newImage = document.createElement('img');
        newImage.src = srcData;

        document.getElementById("imgTest").appendChild(newImage);
        if (index < filesSelected.length) {
          encodeImageFileAsURL(index + 1)
        }
      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
  }
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/74AQhTFeK87GQ5BgPJNx?p=preview

Comment: i tried this code and tried to alert the value but it is only encoding my first uploaded file. How can i print both the encoded values of both the images in one variable?